# Attempting to add a printer via Rendezvous causes printing problems

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, network-printer

I'm attempting to add a network printer (Brother MFC-8840D) to my machine via Rendezvous.

** edit **

The printer is connected to network via an Ethernet cable.  Laptop is connected via wifi.

** / edit **

The printer appears to be added correctly to the printer list.  However, when I print a test page the printer will produce hundreds of pages (if I don't turn off the printer) with the following message:

> ERROR NAME;
>    undefined
>
> COMMAND;
>
> OPERAND STACK;
>    --stringtype--

This behavior has been present since Snow Leopard.

If I add the same printer as 'IP' using the 'Internet Printing Protocol - IPP' and the CUPs driver, however, everything works as expected.

Is this a driver-related issue?  Is Rendezvous attempting to use the 'BR-Script 3' driver?

** edit **

The BR-Script3 driver doesn't cause the problem mentioned earlier.

Comment: As you can indeed get the printer to operate as it should by changing software used to drive the device, it would appear that it is indeed a software (driver) issue that causes it to malfunction, as opposed to a hardware problem.  You do not describe changing how the printer is physically connected to your network, or using a different interface... only changing the software you use to access it.  Apparently Rendezvous *is* attempting to use an incorrect driver.

Comment: Can I force Rendezvous to use the CUPS driver?